# Setting join table attributes when adding objects to a has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails 3.2.3 application, I have two models connected via a third model via a has_many through relationship:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name
  has_many :roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :roles, source: :user
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :fullname
  has_many :roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :organizations, through: :roles
end
```

I want to associate a `User` with an `Organization`.  However, it is required that the `title` attribute on the `Role` be specified.  To enforce this, I have the `title` field set to `NOT NULL` in MySQL.

Here's what happens on the Rails console:

```
>> o = Organization.first
>> u = User.first
>> o.members << u
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `roles` (`created_at`, `organization_id`, `title`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2012-11-22 08:37:23', 1, NULL, '2012-11-22 08:37:23', 1)
Mysql2::Error: Column 'title' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `roles` (`created_at`, `organization_id`, `title`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2012-11-22 08:37:23', 1, NULL, '2012-11-22 08:37:23', 1)
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'title' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `roles` (`created_at`, `organization_id`, `title`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2012-11-22 08:37:23', 1, NULL, '2012-11-22 08:37:23', 1)
    from /path/...
```

I know that I can make a `Role` instance directly.  However, what is the more elegant approach to specifying attributes on join tables when using the `<<` operator?

Comment: Why aren't you using validates presence of in your model instead of putting not null in the db?

Comment: I do have `validates_presence_of :title` in `Role`.  It is enforced at both the model level and the database level.  However, Rails still spits out the MySQL error rather than some validation error.

Comment: Can you remove the validation from the db and see what happens?

Comment: Also, are you likely to have a multitude if different roles or a set amount? For example, admin, accounts, staff?

Comment: In this case, `title` can be anything ("Vice President", "Treasurer", and so on).  I believe strongly in database efficiency, including defining fields as `NOT NULL` and having foreign keys, so I don't want to remove the declaration from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're attempting to update the roles table with information that doesn't belong in there. In your case, a role name should be included in either the organisation or user and not your join table. Either include in the parent model or even **better**, create another join table so you can connect roles with users.

```
class role_users < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, role_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Roles < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :foo, :bar
  has_many :role_users
  has_many :users, :through => :role_users
end    

class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :other, :foo, :bar
  has_many :role_users
  has_many :roles, :through => :role_users
end
```

Then either set these roles up yourself like we do, and add a checkbox or drop down so the user can select. Or let the user enter the information themselves.

Comment: The example in the [Rails ActiveRecord Associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) shows a "join table" having additional fields than the two foreign keys.  I took inspiration from there when designing my schema.

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat with rails. That's just my suggestion to the problem you put in SO.